# How to get access to method in base interface with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepositoryBase
{
    void AddUser(User user);
}
```

`IRepositoryBase` has a method `Update(params object[] entities)`.

Now I want to check what goes into this method in Moq. What I tried is something like this:

```
// ARRANGE
var userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
(...)

// ASSERT
userRepositoryMock.Verify(mock =>
    mock.Update(It.Is<User>(
        u => u.CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Today
          && u.Email == expectedEmail
          && u.FullName == expectedFullName
          && u.Name == expectedUserName)),
       Times.Once,
       "The existing user should be updated with the correct information.");
```

Unfortunately, since the `Update` method is part of the interface where the IUserRepository inherits from I cannot access it. That it is part of the base class can be seen in the error message:

> Moq.MockException
>   Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times (...)
>   
>   Performed invocations:
>   IUserRepository.AddUser(User)
>   IRepositoryBase.Update(System.Object[])
>   IRepositoryBase.SaveChanges()

Does anyone know how to inspect the method calls of a base interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IUserRepository effectively absorbs the members of the base repository so this isn't the issue.

Your Update method takes an object array so this is what you need to verify against. We can see in the performed invocations that your method is indeed being called with an object array. Your verification is set up against just a single User (which the compiler allows due to the params keyword).

The params keyword is really just a compiler trick to make it easier to pass in 0 or more arguments. An array will be created under the hood containing all the arguments.

Comment: Thanks you are right. :-) I fixed it as follows:  `userRepositoryMock.Verify(mock =>
                mock.Update(It.Is<Object[]>(u => 
                    ((User)u[0]).AuthenticationStatus == AuthenticatedStatus.Authenticated
                    && ((User)u[0]).CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Today
                    && ((User)u[0]).Email == expectedEmail
                    && ((User)u[0]).FullName == expectedFullName
                    && ((User)u[0]).Name == expectedUserName)),
                Times.Once,
                "The existing user should be updated with the correct information.")`

Comment: Cool, no worries. I'd also recommend making your base repository generic, rather than having it accept objects. It'll make things more type safe and save you from having to cast all over your code.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you know of a good explanation on how to make a generic repository?

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/